# CSS Trick to overlay other's div border with whitespace?

Tags: css, navigation, overlay, border

How would I go about doing something like on this picture?

[image: Overlayed other's div border with whitespace]

I have tried giving the `li` a background, positioning it `1px` to the right and greater `z-index`, but to no avail.

I also got the idea to give border to the `li`'s and hide the border of the active one, but I need the border to be as long as the content on right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following builds on John's solution and also expands the height of the border to match the height of the content.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li>Item1</li>
            <li class="selected">Item2</li>
            <li>Item3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <p>Some</p><p>really</p><p>long</p><p>content</p><p>...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    display:block;
}
#menu {
    display: table-cell; 
    position:relative;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
#menu ul {
    list-style: none;
}
#menu li {
    margin-right: -1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
}
li.selected {
    border-right: 1px solid white;
}
#content {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3VMyY/8/).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this...

```
li.active {
   position: relative;
   right: -1px;
   padding: 1px;
}
```

So long as the containing `ul` has `overflow: hidden`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the overlapping could be done with another div inside li, with position relative, shifted to the right. But then you have to show/hide it based on selected item.

Answer (score 0):

try one of these:

```
li.active {
   border-right-color: white;
}

li.active {
   border-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I achieve this effect I give each of my list items a right border, but for the selected list item I change the `border-color` to white.

However if you want the right border to expand beyond the list items you need to set the border on the `ul` with a set height, and add a 1px negative margin to the list items.

For example this mark-up

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Item one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item three</a></li>
    <li class="at"><a href="#">Item four</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item five</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item six</a></li>
</ul>
```

And this CSS

```
ul {
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;

}

li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    margin-right: -1px;
}

li.at {
    border-right: 1px solid #FFF;
}
```

Will achieve this result - http://jsfiddle.net/ajcw/3VMyY/